# How to do Proof involving Fermat's Little Theorem and Summation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

> Prove that $23$ divides the number : $$\sum_{i=0}^{22} 231^{22i}$$

I know that $\sum 231^{22i} \equiv 1\pmod {23}$

Also it can be rewritten as $\sum (231^{22})^{i} \equiv 1^{i}\pmod {23} $. But how do I change this into this

$\sum 231^{22i} \equiv 0 \pmod {23} $

Comment: The sum has 23 terms, and each of them is $\equiv 1 \pmod{23}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since : $231^{22i} \equiv  1 \pmod{23}$;

$$\sum_{i=0}^{22} 231^{22i} \equiv \sum_{i=0}^{22} 1^{i} (=1) \pmod{23}$$

Now,

$$\sum_{i=0}^{22} 1 = 23$$

Therefore :
$$\sum_{i=0}^{22} 231^{22i} \equiv 23\pmod{23} \equiv \color{blue}0\pmod{23} $$

$$\text{Therefore}~; \sum_{i=0}^{22} 231^{22i} ~~\text{is divisible by}~  23$$